Youtrack rest api to fetch issues by filter
im not getting the filtered issues based on the type of issue sent with query in api request
https://{baseURL}/api/admin/projects/{prjId}/issues?fields=id,idReadable,project(name),customFields(name,value(name,minutes)),reporter(created,login),created&customFields=Assignee&customFields=Priority&customFields=Fix in Version&customFields=Status&customFields=Type&customFields=Total Dev Estimation&customFields=Estimation&customFields=Total Spent time&customFields=Billable Month&customFields=Due Date&$top=50&query=type:Task
im getting all the issues for the prjId

The /api/admin/projects/{projectID}/issues resource does not support the query parameter. Instead, please use /api/issues and change the query to include the name of the needed project.
You can find more information with examples in the YouTrack REST API reference:  Project Issues, Issues.

Thanks for your ans, actually there is an option to get the issues with ticket type, project name and worker details. by specifying the workItem we can easily get the details.
